# compressing uploaded videos to the app

Tags: java, android, video, compression, jpeg

I'm building an android app in which users upload videos. I want to compress these videos. Can anybody refer me to a relevant code(or any other ways to do it in android)?
 I haven't found java code implementation for MPEG compression.

THANKS!

Comment: Most videos are already compressed, and JPEG is for images, not videos. What format are your videos in, and why do you think that they need to be compressed?

Comment: Im sorry,I meant MPEG of course. The videos are in MP4 format and they need to be compressed because i want each video to be weighted max of 10MB.

Comment: Anyone please?Thanks